# Which method would be more appropriate here POST or PATCH?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Let's say I have a db collection with users and I want to ADD an object to an array inside one document.
It was like this:

```
{
_id: "636e8e1dd710eed71565741c",
username: "test",
password: "$2b$10$/s9.kRYSax380Xrxf3xyVO9Z6Otc/WVx5kBSLKfu43/wYP.TSnzvW",
tasks: [{name: task1, status: "finished"}]
}
```

And I am going to make it look like this:

```
{
_id: "636e8e1dd710eed71565741c",
username: "test",
password: "$2b$10$/s9.kRYSax380Xrxf3xyVO9Z6Otc/WVx5kBSLKfu43/wYP.TSnzvW",
tasks: [{name: task1, status: "finished"}, {name: task2, status: "unfinished"}]
}
```

So which method would be more appropriate here since I'm adding a new object to an embedded array and not updating one which already exists? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice between POST and PATCH depends on the path of the URL. If the path contains the `_id`, I'd prefer

```
POST /collection/636e8e1dd710eed71565741c/tasks
Content-Type: application/json

{"name": "task2", "status": "unfinished"}
```

However, if the `_id` is part of the payload, I'd prefer

```
PATCH /collection
Content-Type: application/json

{"_id": "636e8e1dd710eed71565741c",
 "tasks@add": [{"name": "task2", "status": "unfinished"}]}
```

But this payload format relies on "naming conventions":

- The `_id` serves to identify the entry to be patched.
- The suffix `@add` means that the tasks are added to the existing array.
- `"tasks@change": [{"name": "task1", "status": "archived"}]` would instead update the existing task.

If the server knows that each task is identified by its `name`, the suffixes would not be necessary:

```
PATCH /collection
Content-Type: application/json

{"_id": "636e8e1dd710eed71565741c",
 "tasks": [{"name": "task1", "status": "archived"},
           {"name": "task2", "status": "unfinished"}]}
```

updates the existing task and adds a new one. Or even

```
PATCH /collection/636e8e1dd710eed71565741c/tasks
Content-Type: application/json

[{"name": "task1", "status": "archived"},
 {"name": "task2", "status": "unfinished"}]
```

I hope these examples help you find a suitable pattern.